# Shell executor does not work on registered gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Have an API in production since May, working on server with Gitlab-CI/CD. Everything worked fine till last update (2021:08:10), when the pipelines started to fail.

I could see different errors, like :

> /bin/sh: eval: line 183: docker-compose: not found

or

> /bin/sh: eval: line 183: sudo: not found

or other problems like **file or directory not found** and etc. So fixing one issue was leading to another issue.

I don't show here the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, because I assume the problem is in another place. After spending hours, found out that the pipeline is running with **Docker executor**.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.1.0-rc1 (e9489c8a) 
on docker-auto-scale 0277ea0f 
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
```

Very interesting... Because when registering the runner I've chosen the **executor shell**. And the last successful pipeline 2 months ago was running exactly with executor shell.

I tried to re-register the runner, reset the registration token and register the new one, each time choosing as executor **shell**, but when checking it appears that the pipelines are running with Docker executor.

Does anyone have idea how it is possible and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3016) is the solution.

Settings were changed somehow in gitlab profile, shared runners became enabled and that caused an impact on my runner and executor.